# Android SqLite Cursor.getgetColumnIndex() Doesn't seem o be working

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I'm quite desperate here and can't figure out if there is a bug in my code or if i've done something wrong.
My Problem is in reading a database which stores images as Blobs.
I have followed tutorials to implement this but something seems broken.

First of i created a databaseHelper class that creates my databases.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TBLE_PROFILEIMG + " (" +
            FLD_ALLTABLES_UNIQUEPICID + " INTEGER, " +
            FLD_ALLTABLES_DELETABLE + " BOOLEAN, " +
            FLD_ALLTABLES_PICTURE + " BLOB);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TBLE_EXIMG + " (" +
            FLD_EXERCISE_ID + " TEXT, " +
            FLD_ALLTABLES_DELETABLE + " BOOLEAN, " +
            FLD_ALLTABLES_UNIQUEPICID + " INTEGER, " +
            FLD_ALLTABLES_PICTURE + " BLOB);");

}
```

Then i Created a class to write to the database,
There is no problem here and i am sure everything works on spot because i pulled the database from my device and opened it with SQLite Studio.
The fields are created correctly and images successfully written as BLOB from an array of bytes.

```
public List<MyPicture> getProfilePictures() {
    Cursor c = readTable(ImgDatabaseHelper.TBLE_PROFILEIMG);
    List<MyPicture> bl = new ArrayList<>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        while (true) {
            int colidx = c.getColumnIndex(ImgDatabaseHelper.FLD_ALLTABLES_PICTURE);
            byte[] bb = c.getBlob(colidx);
            Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length);
            if (pic != null)
                bl.add(
                        new MyPicture(
                                pic,
                                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ImgDatabaseHelper.FLD_ALLTABLES_UNIQUEPICID)),
                                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ImgDatabaseHelper.FLD_ALLTABLES_DELETABLE)) > 0
                        )
                );

            if (c.isLast()) break;
            else c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return bl;
}
```

It Can't find the Column:

```
E/CursorWindow﹕ Failed to read row 0, column 2 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 3 columns.
```

The Column surely exists because i verified it in sqlite studio.
and the column index keeps coming back as null.
I am guessing my problem is in the query because the exception says that there are 0 rows when infact i verified that there are 4 rows present.
Here is my readTable method:

```
private Cursor readTable(String table) {
    Cursor crs = null;
    try {
        // Has the same result as the statment under it
        // crs = db.query(table, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        crs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table, null);
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e) { }
    return crs;
}
```

Comment: "which has 0 rows" this is the reason

Comment: Yes i figured, so why is the query returning 0 rows when the table actually has 4 rows in it?

Comment: do a query and pass the Cursor fo DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor()

Comment: That throws the same exception:

W/CursorWindow﹕ Window is full: requested allocation 2512427 bytes, free space 2096696 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
03-31 18:45:29.641  24829-24829/cc.com.mgb W/CursorWindow﹕ Window is full: requested allocation 2512427 bytes, free space 2096696 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
03-31 18:45:29.651  24829-24829/cc.com.mgb E/CursorWindow﹕ Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 3 columns.

Comment: make blobs empty and run it again

Comment: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@45edcd68
<<<<<

Thats all that comes out

Comment: so its empty: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java

Comment: Because i cleared the database, not because it was empty before. If you meant that i should clear only the blobs i misinterpreted. Il'l try that now

Comment: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44bb5310
03-31 19:00:25.421  30386-30386/cc.com.mgb I/System.out﹕ 0 {
03-31 19:00:25.421  30386-30386/cc.com.mgb I/System.out﹕ id=0
03-31 19:00:25.421  30386-30386/cc.com.mgb I/System.out﹕ candel=1
03-31 19:00:25.421  30386-30386/cc.com.mgb I/System.out﹕ pic=<unprintable>
03-31 19:00:25.421  30386-30386/cc.com.mgb I/System.out﹕ }
03-31 19:00:25.421  30386-30386/cc.com.mgb I/System.out﹕ <<<<<

Comment: Yes but i cleared the blobs, i need it to work with the blobs full of images.
Why does it work with empty blobs and not with blobs with data?

Comment: where did you read to store image data as a blob?  its definitely a bad idea, store a path to the phisical file containing the image data instead of using a blob

Comment: Some say to do so, some say to not. I Just thought it was a good idea. Guess not